# Changing navigation bar icons size in Firefox with CSS?

Tags: css, firefox

I want to change the navigation bar value for iconsize to "large" in Australis as it were in Firefox 28 before the dreadful upgrade.

In Australis the new value for iconsize is "small"

[image]

and in Firefox 28 the value is "large".

In the DOM inspector if i change the value from "small" to "large" it changes the icons size back to the old look. But how to make this change permanent?

I tried these css scripts with Stylish but none of them worked:

```
#nav-bar {iconsize='large'}
toolbar > #nav-bar {iconsize='large'}
#nav-bar[iconsize='large']
toolbar[iconsize="large"]
```

I am not very experienced with Firefox css scripts so i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=940953

There's a reported bug in firefox 28 about this.

You can try

```css
 #mytoolbarbutton {
   list-style-image: url(large.png);
 }
 toolbar[iconsize="small"] #mytoolbarbutton {
   list-style-image: url(small.png);
 }
```

or do it the other way round:

```css
 #mytoolbarbutton {
    list-style-image: url(small.png);
 }
 toolbar[iconsize="large"] #mytoolbarbutton {
    list-style-image: url(large.png);
 }
```